# Android Multi screen resolution support

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I am developing an android application as generalized UI development for all devices. Now the Scenario is i want to design for 1024 X 768 resolution, where i kept a separate values folder as follows
For landscape -values-sw720dp-xlarge-land.( It is working fine.)
For portrait -values-sw720dp-xlarge-port. But it is not working.

Comment: What do you mean `not working`?

Comment: 1024 X 768 is it an 10 inch tablet ?

Comment: Its not considering the folder, the components were not aligned according to the values mentioned in that folder.

Comment: @ Padma Kumar it is 9.7 Inch Tablet having 1024 X 768.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this [How to Support Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support)

I expected you will solve from that.

Best of luck!